# How to execute a path in Windows from Python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to write my first tkinter program that involves clicking a button to run a file in Windows

What module would I need/ how would I approach this:

paths are written in a .txt doc -> for loop reads the paths -> creates buttons with command to open the file 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\externalfileIwanttorun.exe

Comment: You can study on os module of Python to address these type of issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subprocess

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\Me\Desktop\\externalfileIwanttorun.exe'])
```